Question: How to Create a Custom WireGuard Client App Using Java in Android Studio?
I am trying to create a custom WireGuard client app using Java in Android Studio. I'm using the com.wireguard.android:tunnel library available on Maven Central. Here are the steps I've followed so far:

Create the WireGuard Configuration

I created a new file in the app's assets directory (e.g., wg0.conf) and added my WireGuard        configuration: 
dependencies {
implementation 'com.wireguard.android:tunnel:1.0.20'
}
`
2. Create the VPN Service
I created a new class that extends WgQuickBackend and implemented the necessary methods:
